# Does UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()) Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

When I call `UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId())` does it cache, or make a call to the database every time it's called?

Comment: I am 99% certain that it does not cache.  If you want it to cache, either setup caching at your DB layer or store leverage from HttpContext cache.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy, I thought that would be the answer... ;)

Comment: No problem - I would post as an answer, but I cannot find anything definitive (MSDN,etc) to support my claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not cache, the underlying store/dbcontext might cache, but the manager itself does no caching, it always calls through to the UserStore.